# form submit after validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to stop form submit by client side validation done by models attribute. i have done every possibilities but mot success.. please look this code:

My Model is

```
[Key]
        public int User_ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter FirstName")]
        public string User_FN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter MiddleName")]
        public string User_MN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter LastName")]
        public string User_LN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter LoginID")]
        public string User_Login { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter PassWord")]
        public string User_Password { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Select a Valid Role")]
        public int User_Role_ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Select any one Table")]
        public List<int> Table_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<bool> P_Add { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<bool> P_Edit { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<bool> P_Delete { get; set; }
```

and i added this reference jquery files

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

and set these keys to

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

all the setting done but page still submitted...Please suggest me

Comment: Please put your action method code to. Where you post the value ?

Comment: That help us to lead you in correct way

Comment: The scripts need to be (in order) `jquery-{version}.js` `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (dont include both `unobtrusive.js` and `unobtrusive.min.js`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load validate.js before validate.unobtrusive.min.js